# Falha na validação de campos

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho um formulário que só habilita o botão avançar, quando o campo é preenchido ou selecionado.  
Os campos **Cód. Assinante**, **Nome do Assinante** e a **Data de Instalação** estão permitindo deletar o seu conteúdo após o preenchimento.  
 
**O Problema é que as pessoas estão preenchendo para habilitar e depois deletam o conteúdo do campo e o botão não desabilita.**  
Esse formulário, só exibe uma pergunta por vez e cada botão, é do tipo buttom e só no final que eu dou um submit.
Por isso que eu não posso utilizar o **required**.  
Segue o código:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt-br">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="Gigaline">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
        <title></title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mpv/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mpv/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mpv/css/estilo.css" type="text/css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="../mpv/css/habilita.css" type="text/css">

<!-- JQuery -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function() {

                $("#datepicker").datepicker({

                    numberOfMonths: 1,

                    maxDate: "0D",
                    dateFormat: "yy'/'mm'/'dd",

                    showAnim: "clip",
                    firstDay: 0,

                    buttonImage: "http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/datepicker/images/calendar.gif",
                    buttonImageOnly: true,
                    yearRange: '2000:2020',
                    monthNames: ["Janeiro", "Feveveiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"],
                    monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Fev", "Mar", "Abr", "Mai", "Jun", "Jul", "Ago", "Set", "Out", "Nov", "Dez"],
                    dayNamesMin: ["Dom", "Seg", "Ter", "Qua", "Qui", "Sex", "Sáb"],
                    onSelect: function() { 

                        $(this).click();

                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row-fluid">
                <div class="well">
                     <h2 class="centraliza_texto">Preencha abaixo os campos:</h2>
    <form action="responde_questionario.php" id="myform" method="post">
                         <div id="myform"> 
                        <div class="centraliza">
                            <fieldset>Cód. Assinante:&nbsp;

                                <input type="text" name="cod_assinante" maxlength="7" class="input-mini" title="Favor inserir o Código do Cliente (Integrator)."  />
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;Ou&nbsp;&nbsp;Assinante:
                                    <input type="text" name="assinante" title="Favor inserir o nome do cliente." />

                                <br />
                                <button type="button" disabled="true" class="avancar btn btn-primary pull-right">Avancar</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Data Instalação -->
                        <div class="centraliza">
                            <fieldset>Data Instalação:&nbsp;
                                <input id="datepicker" type="text" name="data_instalacao" />
                                <br />
                                <br />
                                <button type="button" class="voltar btn btn-primary pull-left">Voltar</button>
                                <button type="button" disabled="true" class="avancar btn btn-primary pull-right">Avancar</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
           <div class="centraliza">
                            <fieldset>
                                <div class="centraliza_texto">
                                    <h4 class="text-info centraliza_texto">
                                        <?php
                                        $query = $con->query("SELECT informacao FROM pv_informacao where ativo = 1 and cod_informacao = 2");
                                        while($reg = $query->fetch_array()) 
                                             {
                                                echo $reg["informacao"];
                                             }
                                        ?>
                                    </h4>
                                    </div>  

                                    <ol style="margin-left: 15%; margin-right: 12%;">
                                        <b><li>Informar sobre alteração de senha na página da Gigaline;</li></b>
                                        <b><li>Informar da segunda via do boleto pela página da Gigaline;</li></b>
                                        <b><li>Informar telefone e Horários de atendimento do suporte e do escritório;<br />sobre alteração de senha na página da Gigaline;</li></b>
                                        <b><li>Informar sobre chuvas com descarga eletromagnéticas.</li></b>
                                    </ol>
                                   <br />

                                   <br />
                                <button type="button" class="voltar btn btn-primary pull-left">Voltar</button>
                                <button type="submit" class="avancar btn btn-primary pull-right">Avancar</button>
                            </fieldset>
                        </div>
</div>
                    </form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $('.centraliza:first').show();
            $('input, select').on('click', function() {
                var fieldset = $(this).closest('fieldset')
                var campos = fieldset.find('input, select');
                var button = fieldset.find('.avancar')[0];
                var preenchido = false;

                campos.each(function() {

                    if (this.value != '') preenchido = true;
                })
                button.disabled = !preenchido;

            });
            $('.avancar').on('click', function() {
                $(this).closest('.centraliza').slideUp().next().slideDown();
//               
            });

            $('.voltar').on('click', function() {
                $(this).closest('.centraliza').slideUp().prev().slideDown();

            });
        </script>
        <script>
            function formatarData(d){
    var data = d || new Date();
    var segundos = data.getSeconds();
    var minutos = data.getMinutes();
    var horas = data.getHours();
    return [horas, minutos, segundos].join(':');
}

var inicio = new Date();
var tempos = [formatarData(inicio)];
$('button.contador').click(function () {
    var agora = new Date();
    tempos.push(formatarData(agora));
});
$('#final').click(function () {
   alert(tempos.join('\n'));
});
        </script>
        <script src="../mpv/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faça o jQuery verificar o campo mesmo que o botão esteja habilitado e o campo vazio. Assim que a pessoa clicar no botão avançar, antes de qualquer ação para redireciona-lá a próxima página, faça algo do tipo:

```
$("#botaoAvancar").on('click', function(){

var campo = $.trim($("#CampoVerificar").val());

if(campo == ''){

$(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
 return false;

      }
});
```

Comment: Legal.
Eu devo colocar esse código no head? Desculpa, mas estou inciando com Jquery.

Comment: Coloque esse código juntamente ao seu. Esse código diz: Após clicar no botão avançar (#botaoavancar) ele irá capturar o valor do campo que tem que ver se tem conteudo (#campoVerificar). Se for vazio, irá desabilitar o botão e retornar false, e continuará na mesma página

Comment: Certo. Mais eu devo colocar dentro de uma tag script? É que eu tentei e não funcionou.
Lebrando que estou usando buttom no lugar de `'<a href="#" >botão</a>`'
Obrigado.

Comment: O seu código não funcionou. Eu coloco dentro do buttom, coloco no head ou o que?
Me ajude, por favor.

Comment: @Jorge B. pode me ajudar?

Comment: . Eu não tenho como utilizar `'#botaoavancar`' porque estou usando `'<button>`' e não `'<a href>`'

Answer (score 1):

Coloque o código do @Alisson dentro das tags `<script></script>`
Ou coloque dentro da sua função já existente, assim:

```
    $('.voltar').on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('.centraliza').slideUp().prev().slideDown(); 
        var campo = $(this).closest(':text').val();
        if(campo == ''){
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Obrigado pela orientação. Irei efetuar os testes.

Comment: Boa tarde, Senhores.
Me desculpem, mas não estou conseguindo.
O código vai no <script></script> dentro do head.
tem algo mais a ser feito?
Obrigado.

Comment: não estou conseguindo.